# Algorith to verify a Sudoku puzzle?

Tags: matlab

Does anyone know an algorithm to verify a sudoku puzzle in Matlab? For the input of matrix S being the puzzle to be checked anf the output TF being 1 if the puzzle is true and 0 if false, I wrote this:

```
TF=1
for i=1:9
if sum(S(i,:))~=45|sum(S(:,i))~=45|sum(sum(S(6*(floor(i/3)+1):6*(floor(i/3)+1)+3,6*(floor(i/3)+1):6*(floor(i/3)+1)+3)))~=45
TF=0
end
end
```

It works by assuming the sum of any row, column, and the 9 3x3 blocks is 45, but it is slow and clunky. Can someone help me clean it up and simplify it?

Comment: Please start by proper indentation (select code in Matlab editor and press `CTRL+I`) and line wrapping (using `...`). I won't have a look before you do that.

Comment: Your code neither works (due to useless indexing) nor is it checking the full Sudoku requirements: 5*ones(9,9) will also have 45 sums for all columns, rows and sub blocks...

Answer (score 0):

The code is modified from the reference: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7676-sudoku

```
TF = 1;
if sum(sum(S))~=405 
   TF=0;
elseif S(1,1) == S(1,2)
   TF=0;
else

   for i=1:9
      for j=1:9
         if i<4          iii=[1 2 3]; end    
         if i>3 && i<7   iii=[4 5 6]; end
         if i>6          iii=[7 8 9]; end
         if j<4          jjj=[1 2 3]; end
         if j>3 && j<7   jjj=[4 5 6]; end
         if j>6          jjj=[7 8 9]; end
         if sum(sum(S(iii,jjj)))~=45
            TF=0;
            break;
         end
      end
   end
   for i=1:9
      if sum(S(i,:))~=45 | sum(S(:,i))~=45 
         TF=0;
         break;
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: `S=5*ones(9,9);S(1,1)=4;S(2,2)=4;S(1,2)=6;S(2,1)=6;` is accepted

Answer (score 0):

This should be a fast version to check sudoku:

```
%% constants:
k=3;
l=k*k;
ix=reshape(1:l^2,l,l);
firstblock=reshape(ix(1:k,1:k),1,l);
blocks=ix(1:k:end,1:k:end);
% create a index matrix which selects: Row 1:9, Col 1:9, Block 1:9
selector=[ix;ix';bsxfun(@plus,firstblock,blocks(:)-1)];
valid=repmat([1:l],l*3,1);
%% check:
C=sort(S(selector),2);
okay=all(all(C==valid))
```

For a new solution only the `check`-Part has to be repeated, which is below 0.0001s on my pc.